# Getting Jersey in Tomcat to return plain errors

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Spring/Jersey application running in Tomcat. There is a JAX-RS exception mapper which intercepts some exceptions and returns `Response` like:

```
Response.serverError().type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .entity("My custom error message").build();
```

In debugger I can see that it is  returning what I expect.

Later on I see that Jersey's `ResponseWriter` calls:

```
response.sendError(500, "Internal Server Error");
```

... But finally the output that I get from Tomcat is a full HTML error page, not a plain short string that I set as response entity and saw being written to `HttpServletResponse`.

How can I prevent Tomcat from intercepting and overriding my response body in this case?